# How to get just the file URL from the API

Tags: directus

When I specify fields in my API request for most things I get the single value. However when I want just the URL of a file, I get everything, or more than I want.  If I specify **file.data.url** in my filter I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue of the Directus. Currently, fields in the `param` are working with the column of the database table.
The value of `data` variable is not the part of `directus_files` table.

Currently, you need to use the `data` object with all the values.

Answer (score 0):

Add **fields** as paramater to request
`?fields=file.data.full_url`

I would recommend full_url rather than url as url is relative.